# How did the civil calendar evolve?

Tags: roman-republic, calendar, julius-caesar

**Questions**

1. When did the lunar-inspired subdivisions of months - the kalends, nones, and ides - and the system of counting down to them, fall into disuse, to be replaced with the modern system of counting up across the period of the whole month?
2. When did the system of holding the "bisextile" day for 48 hours fall into total disuse, to be fully replaced by the insertion of an additional day numbered 29 at the end of the Feb month?

**Background**

I've been researching over the past few years the evolution of the practices of keeping a civil calendar, from the "Roman Republican" calendar, to the Julian, to the Gregorian.

Needless to say, the pre-Julian calendar is difficult to fully characterise.

One clear point appears to be that the calendrical "month" has its origin in tracking the phase of the moon, but the only hard evidence remaining of Roman calendrical practices dates from later years of the Republic when any correspondence with the observable lunar phase must have been lost (at least anything beyond a 'stopped clock being right twice a day' sort of correspondence).

The evidence appears to suggest that the original length of the Roman Republican calendrical year was not 365 days, but generally somewhat less, and so the correspondence between the months of the calendar and the seasons was originally maintained on an ad-hoc basis by the intercalation of whole months, according to the judgment of Roman clergy.

But indeed by time of the Julian reform, any correspondence with the solar seasons had also been lost - firstly on account of political meddling in the maintenance of the calendar (as political offices were renewed annually, as reckoned by the calendar), and finally a large amount of foreign war which led to intercalations being neglected.

This led to the "years of confusion" which culminated in the Julian rationalisation.

One could speculate that lunar calendars are of most practical use to sea-faring cultures, as the moon regulates tidal waters and night-time visibility, whereas solar calendars are of primary interest to agrarian cultures as the sun regulates temperatures and growing conditions.

Since the pre-Julian calendar had lost relation to both moon and finally also the solar seasons, one can speculate that by its final stages it was existing purely to coordinate civil and military activity taking place predominantly on dry land.

This is reinforced by accounts which suggest it was seen as "unlucky" to intercalate the calendar in years of major wars - probably on account of the difficulty of communicating the change to the active soldiery located at a distance from Rome, and the confusion and incoordination that would ensue from intercalation during military campaigns (or only shortly before they were expected).

The Julian reform commencing in January 45BC introduced a fixed 365-day calendar year, and restored the traditional correspondence between particular months and the solar seasons. But it also retained lunar trappings, not only in its retention of the "month" period itself, but also in the continued subdivision of its months into three periods of kalends, nones, and ides.

The last day of each of these periods represented in principle the new phase, waxing quarter phase, and full phase of moon, respectively. But even following the Julian reform, the lengths of the Julian months, and their subdivisions, meant there was no intended correspondence to the lunar reality.

Each individual day of the calendar was reckoned as a count down to the final day in each of these lunar-inspired periods.

I would assume, speculating again, that the primary practical reason for the retention of these lunar-inspired periods, was to work within the calendrical concepts that were already traditional, and maintain (at least as much as possible) the placement and reckoning of birthdays, annual feasts and holidays, and other civil activities which the pre-Julian calendar was regulating.

Another innovation of the Julian reform was the introduction of a "bisextile" day every four years. This is the analogue of what nowadays is the Feb 29 leap day.

But originally this "bisextile" day occurred on Mar Kal 6 (the equivalent to the modern Feb 24), and was reckoned not by the insertion of an additional day into the calendar as such, but by holding the calendar at Mar Kal 6 for 48 hours (or two 'natural' days). Hence the name "bisextile" - loosely, the "doubled sixth" day.

It should be noticed that the "first" day, in this down-counting scheme, falls later, in this case being Mar Kal 1 (equivalent to the modern Mar 1).

I'm also not exactly representing above how the Romans spoke of these days - they apparently spoke of "ante diem 3 Kal Mar" (3rd day before, or Mar Kal 3), "pridie Kal Mar" (the day before, or Mar Kal 2), and "Kal Mar" (the day of the kalends, or Mar Kal 1) - but using a conceptually-consistent representation of the sequence which I at least find more consistent and less confusing.

My understanding is that at some later point, it became conventional to explicitly distinguish between the first and second natural day of the bisextile calendar day, although when this system was still in use, the two days were still reckoned as the first and second days of Feb 24 (or Mar Kal 6).

If it's pertinent, I'm primarily interested in when these changes became established in England (or later, the UK), but I'm equally interested in where the changed practices may have first originated and spread.

Comment: Medieval manuscripts that I have seen still count backward, and the Tridentine reforms in the Catholic church still counted backward (you can tell from how saints feast days in late Feb shifted on Leap Years).  But I've never seen early modern documents that count backward. So I'm guessing the happened gradually in 14th-16th centuries.   But I'm not sure enough to make this an answer.

Comment: Also note that it wasn't ever a pure counting backward system. Pagan Roman feasts were almost uniformly on odd days counting *forward*, which are even days counting backwards from the Kalends but odd days counting backward from the Nones or the Ides

Comment: Also note that *ante diem* is almost invariably abbreviated *a.d.* (lower case) and that the numeral is always lower case Roman, e.g. *a.d  vi Kal. Mar.*

Comment: @CMonsour, with regards to the saints days in leap years, they are shifted because they fall at fixed offsets prior to Easter Day (which falls Mr22 to Ap25), so it isn't directly related to this down-counting issue. In the original bisextile scheme, the saints days always fell on the same calendar day, leap year or no, because Feb 24 was reckoned as a single calendar day for all purposes (whether it lasted 24 hours or 48).

Comment: @CMonsour, as I said in my question, the two natural days of the bisextile were *later* accounted separately. As you say, as Mar Kal 6 and Mar Kal 6 Bis. But even when this was done, it wasn't originally consistent which was the first and which was the second in sequence (i.e. whether the bis day fell before the non-bis day, or after), and for all legal, religious, and other formal purposes, they were the same calendar day of the year, even if they were clearly two different natural days.

Comment: @CMonsour, your points do raise an interesting question however about whether the *weekdays* were held for 48 hours across the bisextile! I believe the 7-day weekday cycle has never been interrupted since time immemorial, so I suspect even if the monthday did not change across the bisextile, the weekday did change - so you'd have had, for example, a Saturday 24 Feb followed by a Sunday 24 Feb, and people would have used that device to distinguish which natural day they were referring to within the bisextile period.

Comment: I'm talking about saints feasts.  Those are *not* at fixed offsets with respect to Easter, but at fixed dates on the calendar.  For example, the feat of St. Joseph is 19 March.  The Feast of St. Matthias on the traditional calendar is 24 February in normal years and 25 February in Leap Years (which, by the way, confirms that a.d. bis vi Kal Mar came before a.d. vi Kal Mar).  And it doesn't last 48 hours in Leap Years!

Comment: @CMansour, I find it interesting to note that the weekday calendar is essentially a completely independent calendar from that which reckons months and years - and has proven to be the most universal and resilient cycle of timekeeping over the ages. The Romans, of course, originally had an 8-day week system, and only later with the influence of Christianity did the 7-day week become the norm for civil purposes (with accounts I've seen suggesting that the 7-day week originated in Judaism).

Comment: Also, no calendar ever had two February 24's.  If at some early stage no one but a bis in front of the first of the two a.d. vi Kal Mar dates, they certainly had done long before people stopped counting backward.  February 24 is called the bissextile day in a Leap Year because it had *bis* in its name in the old system, NOT because it was 48 hours long.

Comment: @CMonsour, ah right, with regard to St. Matthias, I understand from a brief lookup, that this saint's day was only introduced in the 11th century, so quite possibly well after the bisextile had started to be accounted for as two separate calendar days (although of course, when this happened is one of my main questions).

Comment: Also interesting is that these last 5 days of February were an interesting period in the pagan Roman religion since a.d. vii Kal Mar (Feb 23) was essentially the last day of the religious year, Kal Mar (March 1) was the first day of the new year, and those five days (or the intercalary month which sometimes replaced them) were an "in-between" period.

Comment: @CMonsour, I'm not contending that any calendar ever had two Feb 24s. It's precisely my understanding that, at the inception of the Julian system, the calendar had only one such day, but that in leap years that calendar day was held for 48 hours, rather than the normal 24. If I'm wrong about what I've previously gathered - and I may well be wrong - then please correct me with reference to some authority.

Comment: Your claim is rather surprising, so perhaps you should cite a source.  I'm trying to be helpful, but if I had time to put together references I'd be writing an answer, not comments.

Comment: @CMonsour, in the Julian system, Jan Kal 1 was explicitly fixed as the start of the year, although I acknowledge that there have been varying practices since (indeed the British tended to treat Mar 25 as the start of the year for many purposes, at least in the latter centuries of their use of the Julian calendar up to 1752).

Comment: Steve, March 1 was the Roman religious new year.  It was also the political new year (the day the new consuls took office) until the mid-2nd century BC, when that was transferred to Jan 1.

Comment: If you want to know when they started counting forward in England, I suspect the Paston letters would be a good source for the 15th century

Comment: You are confusing the Julian system with the Roman calendar, which is *much* older.  Before the 2nd century BC, March 1 was the only new year the Roman calendar knew.

Comment: @CMonsour, I'll have to try and clarify my own understanding about the 48 hour point then. It would simply have been helpful if you did have references to consider, as I find sources in general do not speak with one voice about all aspects of this subject, and although I haven't got a reference to hand, I have definitely seen a source recently that say it was not clear which day was the bis and which was the non-bis (which reinforces that it was not a specific second day inserted into the Julian calendar, but simply a later attempt to distinguish the two natural days that it consists of).

Comment: @CMonsour, I've said myself that the Roman Republican calendar is difficult to characterise, and I wouldn't be looking to go back as far as 2nd century BC. Clearly, I am only concerned with going as far back as the Julian system, or contrasting it with what came more or less *immediately* before. I'm aware the start of the year was moved from Mar Kal 1 to Jan Kal 1 with the Julian. But there was no bisextile before the Julian, so what came before wouldn't be especially pertinent to the interpretation of how the bisextile was first accounted for in the Julian.

Comment: @CMonsour, I will say one thing, your mention of St. Matthias is helpful, because as you say it makes clear that by the 11th century the bis came before the non-bis, and there was a clear distinction being made between the bis and the non-bis by that time, and hence why that saint's day falls a day later in leap Februaries in the modern up-counting scheme. Similarly, we can assume the move to up-counting is much more recent than the 11th century.

Comment: I think you missed my reference to the Council of Trent, which made changes to the liturgical calendar in the mid-16th century and kept St, Mattthias's feast the way it was.  That means at least some folks were still counting backward in the 16th century, though possibly only for traditional reasons and possibly not in England

Comment: I think you completely missed the point of my remark about the old Roman religious calendar: It's the only explanation for *why* leap day was inserted at that point.

Comment: Similarly the pre-Julian calendar is what made pagan feasts fall on even days counting back from the Kalends but odd counting back from the Nones or Ides (since every month except Feb had either 29 or 31 days).  That's how we know they sometimes counted forward even though they named the days counting backward.

Comment: You can even tell which months originally had 31 days (March, May, July October) since the Julian calendar kept their Nones and Ides on the 7th and 15th, whereas all other months have them on the 5th and 13th. You can't really understand quite a bit about the Julian calendar without understanding what came before.

Comment: @CMonsour, yes certainly, I'm aware of why the bisextile was inserted at Feb 24, as this represented the "Terminalia". I gather the Ides were really the traditional focal point of the month, and the Nones were the Id 9 of the month (hence the name, if we reckon it down-counting to Id 1), and the Kalends were the Id 13 or Id 15 (depending on the month). I don't quite follow how you conclude that they sometimes up-counted (although I'm not suggesting it is implausible that practice had varied previously). From what I understand, odd numbers were considered pleasing to the gods. (1/2)

Comment: It is very difficult to understand why the lunar elements remained important though, given that the calendar had long since abandoned any connection to the lunar reality. As I say in my question, the only explanation I imagine is that it had less to do with superstition, and more to do with maintaining the civil settlement with the peasantry who would likely have been suspicious about the motives for any change in the arrangement days of festival or obligation, and disinclined (in a pre-literate society) to learn and verbally communicate a new conceptual system of dating. (2/2)

Comment: If you want some primary sources for contemporary writing of dates, I suspect the original texts of the acts of church councils are relatively accessible, as well as the promulgation of the Gregorian calendar.  That last, along with the Councils of Florence and of Trent, and the 5th Lateran Council, should cover the 1400s and 1500s in Italy pretty well.